# Make Teracopy the only choice and remove the default win 10 copy application

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, teracopy

I Screenshot of Teracopy showing whenever I copy any file

[image]

I want windows 10 to automatically choose teracopy ,Instead of asking me everytime I try to copy any file or move any file. Windows 10 should make teracopy default one.

FYI: I have already choosen teracopy as my defualt copy application inside teracopy application.But I guess,this is not working properly. I have also included the screenshot for this setting page of teracopy.

screenshot of teracopy setting
[image: Screenshot of Teracopy showing whenever I copy any file]

Answer (score 9):

When the menu appears, click the gear at the top right. "Show next time" will be selected. Click on it again to deselect it. Next time you paste, the menu will not be shown and Teracopy will paste files as the default app.

[image: Teracopy context menu]

Comment: What if I need windows default and not the teracopy.

Comment: @rahim.nagori The simplest solution will be to remove Teracopy as the menu is handled by it. Do you want to keep both but use Widows as the default?

Comment: How do you enable "Show next time" again?

Comment: @yoonghm Open Tera Copy -> Preferences, then enable "Confirm drag and drop".